# Why is the second Materialise carousel greyed out / not showing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, materialize

I am creating a single-page website and I wanted to add a second carousel to show different client logos.

When I added a second carousel, it seems to be greyed out. I tried to see if it was a syntax error by copying the code from the banner section and pasting it into the client section but it is still greyed out.

I also tried making another js variable called slider2 and renamed the div class slider2 but then only 1 image shows, extremely zoomed in and large and then also overlaying the next sections and adding a lot of white space after the next section also.

```js
//sidenav
const sideNav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
M.Sidenav.init(sideNav, {});

//slider
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
M.Slider.init(slider, {
    indicators: false,
    height: 500,
    transition: 500,
    interval: 12000
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9304c4eb40.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js "></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav class="green darken-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                     <a href="" class="brand-logo"> <i class="material-icons large white-text">insert_chart</i></a> 
                    <a href="#" data-target="mobile-nav" class="sidenav-trigger">
                        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

 
    <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#clients">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <section id="" class="section section-popular">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" class="overlay">
                    <div class="caption hide-on-small-only center">
                        <h2>TEST</h2>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only banner-title-center">TEST</h5>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#contact" class="myButton">CONTACT US</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" class="overlay">
                    <div class="caption hide-on-small-only center">
                        <h2>TEST</h2>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only banner-title-center">TEST</h5>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#contact" class="myButton">CONTACT US</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/3.jpg" class="overlay">
                    <div class="caption hide-on-small-only center">
                        <h2>TEST</h2>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">TEST</h5>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#contact" class="myButton">CONTACT US</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <section id="home" class="section section-popular grey lighten-3">
            <div class="section section-icons align-left">
                <div class="container">
                    <hr/>
                    <h5 class="center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and </h5>
                    <hr/>
                    <p class="intro-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                    <div class="container-box">
                        <p class="style=" font-size: small;>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>

    <section id="clients" class="section section-popular">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="slider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/4.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/5.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/6.png">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you're using `document.querySelector` which only returns the first ".slider" element, instead of `document.querySelectorAll` to select the all the sliders on that page. Since you have multiple sliders with the same class name you should use `querySelectorAll`.

Try the code bellow:

```js
//sidenav
const sideNav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
M.Sidenav.init(sideNav, {});

//slider
const slider = document.querySelectorAll('.slider'); // <- Using querySelectorAll
M.Slider.init(slider, {
    indicators: false,
    height: 500,
    transition: 500,
    interval: 12000
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9304c4eb40.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js "></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav class="green darken-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                     <a href="" class="brand-logo"> <i class="material-icons large white-text">insert_chart</i></a> 
                    <a href="#" data-target="mobile-nav" class="sidenav-trigger">
                        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

 
    <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#clients">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <section id="" class="section section-popular">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" class="overlay">
                    <div class="caption hide-on-small-only center">
                        <h2>TEST</h2>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only banner-title-center">TEST</h5>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#contact" class="myButton">CONTACT US</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" class="overlay">
                    <div class="caption hide-on-small-only center">
                        <h2>TEST</h2>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only banner-title-center">TEST</h5>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#contact" class="myButton">CONTACT US</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/3.jpg" class="overlay">
                    <div class="caption hide-on-small-only center">
                        <h2>TEST</h2>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">TEST</h5>
                        <br>
                        <a href="#contact" class="myButton">CONTACT US</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <section id="home" class="section section-popular grey lighten-3">
            <div class="section section-icons align-left">
                <div class="container">
                    <hr/>
                    <h5 class="center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and </h5>
                    <hr/>
                    <p class="intro-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                    <div class="container-box">
                        <p class="style=" font-size: small;>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>

    <section id="clients" class="section section-popular">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="slider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/4.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/5.png">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/6.png">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```